# How to solve this kind of error while frozen_graph.py

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

How i can solve this kind of error while frozen_graph.py. i passed the parameter for getting frozen file from checkpoint. But while executing it show me

AssertionError: Openpose/concat_stage7 is not in graph

this type of error.

Comment: Hi there. Please show your code instead of describing it. It will help people to answer you.

Comment: It is default tensorflow file, you can get in python/tools folder we need to only pass file in argument